# Does a path exist through all vertices of a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, directed-graph

Given G, a directed graph, is there a path (not necessarily a simple path) that goes through all the vertices in G?

I first need to examine what happens in an acyclic graph and in a strongly-connected graph, and then to find a solution for a general graph, using the graph of the strongly connected components.

So far I have figured out that for a strongly connected graph there is always a path. For an acyclic graph, if there is more than one source a path will never exist. Also, if there is a vertex for which D out is greater than 1, a path will never exist.

The problem is, I'm not sure that last one is right, and if it's wrong, my algorithm is wrong.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve the problem? Or if the last assumption is correct [hint: it is not, for example `E = {(v_i,v_j) | i < j }`, there are vertices such that `d_out(v)`>1, and there still is a path that traverses all vertices - even an hamiltonian one actually]

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure about the last one and you confirmed it.. So I need some help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The last assumption is not true**, for example have a look at the graph `G = (V,E)`, where `E = {(v_i,v_j) | i < j }` The graph is obviously a DAG. so finding the maximal strongly connected component won't change the graph. Also - the graph has a hamiltonian path, however `d_out(v_1) > 1` [assuming `|V| > 3`].

However - you are on the right track.

**Algorithm in high level pseudo code:**

1. find Maximal Strongly Connected Components in the graph - the
   resulting graph is a DAG.
2. Use topological sort on the resulting graph<sup>1</sup>.
3. Check if the ordered sorting creates a hamiltonian path
4. if it is - return true, else return false

**Claim:**

> A path with all vertices exists if and only if the DAG representing
>   the MSCC of the graph has hamiltonian path

**Proof of claim:**

**<-** 

if there is a hamiltonian path - then such a path is trivial, for each MSCC - the path goes through all vertices, and then to the out edge that is representing the our edge that was chosen in the hamiltonian path in the MSCC graph.

**->**

If such a path exists, let it be `v0->v1->...vm`.

Let's denote `V_i` the maximal strongly connected component in which `v_i` lays.

Now, for the path in the original graph `v0->v1->...->vm`, there is also a path in the MSCC graph<sup>2</sup>: `V_0->V_1->...->V_m`.

Note that if `V_i` appears twice [or more] in the above path - the two occurances are adjacent to each other, otherwise the MSCC found is not maximal because if `V_i->V_k->...->V_i` is feasible path - then V_i and V_k are not maximal, since you can unite them into one bigger SCC.

Now, for each `V_i` collapse all occurances of it into one, and you get yourself a path - where each `V_i` appears at most once [we just showed why], and exactly one [since every `v_i` was on the original path and we did not remove MSCC's completely - just collapsed them].

Thus - the generated path is a hamiltonian path in the MSCC graph.

**Proof of correctness of the suggested algrotithm:**

Since we showed hamiltonian path in MSCC graph exists if and only if there exists a requested path in the original graph - then:

**->**

The algorithm returned true -> The algorithm found a Hamiltonian path in the DAG -> There is a Hamiltonian Path in the Dag [foot-note 1] -> There is a path as requested in the original graph.

**<-**

The algorithm returned false -> The algorithm did not find a Hamiltonian pat in the DAG -> There is no hamiltonian path in the DAG [foot-note 1] -> There is no path as requested in the original path.

**Q.E.D.**

---

1: in a DAG, there is a unique topological sort if there exists a hamiltonian path, and if there is a hamiltonian path - it is the order of the vertices in the topological sort. Thus, in a DAG - finding a hamiltonian path is easy.

2: Actually, it is a bit modification, `V_i->V_i` is not really an edge on the MSCC, graph but for now let's denote it as one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... But isn't Hamilton path is necessarily a simple path??

Comment: @Nusha: It is, but I am claiming there is a hamiltonian path in the DAG representing the MSCC of the graph, not the graph itself. a hamiltonian path in the MSCC graph implies a path with all vertices on the original graph.

Comment: @Nusha: I added more detailed explanation [and a proof] why the algorithm is correct.