# Finding any path that visits every node of a directed, unweighted graph

Tags: complexity-theory, graph-theory

Didn't find an answer to this question on SO yet; there were many similar questions, in particular many Qs were asking about *the shortest* path that visits every node of a graph, but still I didn't find an answer to this Q:

Given a directed, unweighted graph, is there *any* path that visits all nodes (not necessarily exactly once)?

Is there an algorithm that solves this problem in a polynomial time?

Comment: Are you looking for a circuit or for a simple path?

Comment: @Holt A path, not a cycle (that is, the path doesn't need to end at the same node it starts from), though if the answer would be different for a path and for a cycle this would be interesting on its own.

Comment: For a cycle, you basically wants to check if your graph is a single strongly connected component, which can be done in linear time (e.g., with Tarjan's algorithm). For a path, I think you can get around with some iterations of DFS, but it is less direct.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186576/does-a-path-exist-through-all-vertices-of-a-directed-graph